# Oracle - Format number with fullstop for thousand and comma for decimals

Tags: sql, oracle, number-formatting

I've a number like this 3225,69 and I want to convert the display to:

```
3.225,69
```

Simply, I need full stop to separate thousand and comma to separate decimals:

```
3,69 -> 3,69 
1000 -> 1.000 
1500,20 -> 1.500,20
1 -> 1 (not 1,000)
```

Which mask should I use in to_char?

I'm my DB columns the comma means decimals.

Comment: Are the numbers stored in the database / variables as numbers, or are they strings?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions201.htm#SQLRF06130

Comment: Are stored as NUMBER in database column. Right now i'm using the mask 9G999G999D000 that works for numbers as 32546,122 (this is converted in 32.546,122). But if i put a number as 1000 the conversion is 1.000,000 (the 3 zero after the comma must be away). Is like to say "the 000 after the D in the mask shuld be optional, dont put this if not necessary"

Comment: So end your mask with `D999` instead of `D000`?

Comment: Nothing change, If i use the mask 9G999G999D999 and i try to format the number 1, i get: 1,000

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `FM` [format modifier](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00216) to have trailing decimal zeros blanked out:

```
select to_char(1, 'FM9G999G999D999', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS='',.''') from dual;

TO_CHAR(1,'FM9G999G999D999','NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS='',.''')
------------------------------------------------------------
1,
```

But as you can see that leaves the decimal character behind; you can trim that off though:

```
with t as (
 select 3.69 as n from dual
 union all select 1000 from dual
 union all select 150.20 from dual
 union all select 1 from dual
 union all select 0.16 from dual
)
select n,
  to_char(n, '9G999G999D000') original,
  to_char(n, 'FM9G999G999D999', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS='',.''') new,
  rtrim(to_char(n, 'FM9G999G999D999', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS='',.'''),
    ',') as trimmed
from t;

         N ORIGINAL       NEW            TRIMMED       
---------- -------------- -------------- --------------
      3.69          3.690 3,69           3,69           
      1000      1,000.000 1.000,         1.000          
     150.2        150.200 150,2          150,2          
         1          1.000 1,             1            
       .16           .160 ,16            ,16
```

I'm using the optional third NLS argument to [the `to_char()` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17118/functions201.htm) to set the G and D characters independently from my session settings.

If you want to preserve the zero befor the decimal separator, just make the last `9` before the `D` into a `0`:

```
with t as (
 select 3.69 as n from dual
 union all select 1000 from dual
 union all select 150.20 from dual
 union all select 1 from dual
 union all select 0.16 from dual
)
select n,
  to_char(n, '9G99G990D000') original,
  to_char(n, 'FM9G999G990D999', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS='',.''') new,
  rtrim(to_char(n, 'FM9G999G990D999', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS='',.'''),
    ',') as trimmed
from t;

         N ORIGINAL      NEW            TRIMMED       
---------- ------------- -------------- --------------
      3.69         3.690 3,69           3,69           
      1000     1,000.000 1.000,         1.000          
     150.2       150.200 150,2          150,2          
         1         1.000 1,             1              
       .16         0.160 0,16           0,16
```

Comment: With this formula i have a "small" problem. If the number is 0,16 i get ,16. I lost the initial ZERO

Comment: @Mistre83 - updated with a version that uses the `...0D...` format model.

Comment: Wow..... to get this works i was used a stupid workaround that add zeros if the first character was a comma........  I have really difficult to understand that formula. Do you know a website that explain all this kind of format? I've tried to search on the net but nothing. Usually i want to understand what i write. The solution is perfect working, but i want understand it too :)

Comment: @Mistre83 - I already [linked to the doc that has the number format models](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00211). That shows what the `FM`, `D`, `G`, `9` and `0` elements do. There are so many permutations possible you're unlikely to find an exact match explained elsewhere, maybe.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
select rtrim(to_char(to_char(1, 'FM9G999G999D999', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS='',.'''), 'FM9G999G999D999', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS='',.'''),',') from dual;
```

I hope help you